# Splitting regex matches by newlines in perl

Tags: regex, perl, subroutine, perl-data-structures

I am trying to  glob files from a directory and print out regexp matches, 
Trying to match

```
 <110> 
    *everything here*
 <120>
```

My matches would be

```
SCHALLY, ANDREW V. 
CAI, REN ZHI
      ZARANDI, MARTA
```

However when i try to split this by newline and join using "|", I am not getting the desired output that is

```
Applicant :  SCHALLY, ANDREW V. | CAI, REN ZHI | ZARANDI, MARTA
```

My current output is only

```
 |        ZARANDI, MARTA
```

Can someone see any obvious mistakes?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use IO::Handle;

open (my $fh, '>', '../logfile.txt')  || die "can't open logfile.txt";
open (STDERR, ">>&=", $fh)         || die "can't redirect STDERR";
$fh->autoflush(1);



my $input_path = "../input/";
my $output_path = "../output/";
my $whole_file;

opendir INPUTDIR, $input_path or die "Cannot find dir $input_path : $!";
my @input_files = readdir INPUTDIR;
closedir INPUTDIR;

foreach my $input_file  (@input_files) 
{   
    $whole_file = &getfile($input_path.$input_file); 
    if ($whole_file){
        $whole_file =~  /[<][1][1][0][>](.*)[<][1][2][0][>]/s ;
        if ($1){
            my $applicant_string = "Applicant : $1";
            my $op = join( "|", split("\n", $applicant_string) );
            print $op; 
        }
    }
}

close $fh;




sub getfile {
    my $filename = shift;
    open F, "< $filename " or die "Could not open $filename : $!" ;
    local $/ = undef; 
    my $contents = <F>;
    close F;
    return $contents;
}
```

### EDIT 1

I Ran Code on a single file

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use IO::Handle;


my $input_file = "01.txt-WO13_090919_PD_20130620";
my $input_path = "../input/";

my $whole_file = &getfile($input_path.$input_file); 


if ($whole_file =~  /[<][1][1][0][>](.*)[<][1][2][0][>]/s ) {
        print $1;
            my @split_string = split("\n", $1);
            my $new_string =  join("|", @split_string) ;
            print "$new_string \n";
}



sub getfile {
    my $filename = shift;
    open F, "< $filename " or die "Could not open $filename : $!" ;
    local $/ = undef; 
    my $contents = <F>;
    close F;
    return $contents;
}
```

Output

```
  Chen, Guokai
       Thomson, James
       Hou, Zhonggang

        Hou, Zhonggang
```

Comment: What's your actual input? And output? Your 'whole file' re match is only going to match once - is that what you intended?

Comment: Input is multiple files, I glob each file and use regex on a whole file, Yes once per file is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run your code and get

```
|SCHALLY, ANDREW V. |CAI, REN ZHI|      ZARANDI, MARTA
```

Which is pretty close. all you need to do is trim whitespace before you join. So replace this

```
 my @split_string = split("\n", $1);
 my $new_string =  join("|", @split_string) ;
```

With this:

```
 my @split_string = split("\n", $1);
 my @names;
 foreach my $name ( @split_string ) {
   $name =~ s/^\s*(.*)\s*$/$1/;
   next if $name =~ /^$/; 
   push @names, $name;
 }

 my $new_string =  join("|", @names);
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
$whole_file =~  /[<][1][1][0][>](.*)[<][1][2][0][>]/s ;
if ($1) {
```

with

```
if ($whole_file =~ /[<][1][1][0][>](.+)[<][1][2][0][>]/s) {
```

The problem with your original code is that `$1` is unchanged (i.e. retained from the previous file) if the regexp doesn't match.

If that doesn't solve the problem, then double check and make sure that you have the correct value if `$applicant_string`. Your join + split line looks correct.

Comment: I'd be tempted to do the regexp test in a list context, and assign the match directly, rather than use `$`. That way your result is undef if the match fails.

Answer (score 1):

@pts is correct, the regex capture variables do not get reset to UNDEF
upon a negative match, looks like they retain their last value.

So his solution should work for you.  Use the `if ( $whole_file =~ // ) {}` form.

Beyond that, you could clean up the operation a little by doing something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;
my $whole_file = <DATA>;

if ( $whole_file =~ /[<][1][1][0][>](.*)[<][1][2][0][>]/s )
{
    my $applicant_string = $1;
    $applicant_string =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    my $op = "Applicant : " . join( " | ", split( /\s*\r?\n\s*/, $applicant_string) );
    print $op; 
}

__DATA__

          <110>


  SCHALLY, ANDREW V. 
CAI, REN ZHI
      ZARANDI, MARTA

  <120>
```

Output:

```
Applicant : SCHALLY, ANDREW V. | CAI, REN ZHI | ZARANDI, MARTA
```

Comment: /\s*(?:\r?\n)+\s*/ splitting with this regexp worked

Comment: what does regex capture in a split statement do?

Comment: @Stacked-for-life -It does an internal trim. Uh, capture in a split statement inserts what's captured in an element.